# I have a code with api, writing on react and laravel

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to realize the opening of a certain post, but when selecting the link changes and all the details of the post are displayed on the main page, and I would like to have a transition to a new page.Already even no guesses how it can be finished, I want to say at once that in this I am a beginner and ask without strong criticism

```
App.js
    function App() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="App">
                   <Header />
                   <Wrapper />
                   <Routes>
                       <Route exact path="/post/:id" element={<PostDetail />} />
                   </Routes>
                </div>
             </Router>
        );
    }

PostDetails.js
    function PostDetail() {
        const { id } = useParams();
        const [post, setPost] = useState({});

        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post?id=${id}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => setPost(data))
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }, [id]);

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Детали поста</h2>
                <img className="card__image" src={post.image} alt=""/>
                <p>Заголовок: {post.name}</p>
                <p>Содержание: {post.description}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

RecentlyUpdate.js

     return (
            <>
                <div className="wrapper__recently">
                    <div className="wrapper__title">
                        {categories.map(category => (
                            <h1 className="title" key={category.id}>
                                {category.name}
                            </h1>

                        ))}
                        <p className="subTitle">
                            {dateTime}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="wrapper__recently_scrollSection">
                        <div className="wrapper__recently__row">
                            {posts.map(post => (

                                <div className="recently__card" >
                                    <Link key={post.id} to={`/post/${post.id}`}>
                                        <div className="card__img">
                                            <img className="card__image" src={post.image}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </Link>
                                    <div className="card__miniNav">
                                        <div className="wrapper__recently__tags">
                                            <span>DUB</span>
                                            <span>SUB</span>
                                            {/*<p>TV</p>*/}
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="addToFavorite">
                                            <img src={FavoriteIcon} alt=""/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="animeName">
                                        <p className="title__anime">
                                            {post.name}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

Tried chatting with chat gpt, but never came to a sensible answer

Comment: Sorry, i complete that